# RFM analysis by month in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I did a RFM analysis in pandas recently on a year of transactions, but now I want to give RFM scores to every customer for every month, my dataframe looks like this:

```
txn_id | customer_id | date     | total
1      | 2           | 2016-1-2 | 30
2      | 5           | 2016-1-3 | 21
3      | 2           | 2016-1-4 | 9
4      | 3           | 2016-3-2 | 10
5      | 2           | 2016-3-1 | 10
```

To calculate the RFM score on a whole year, I used

```
now = dt.datetime(2016,12,31)
df.groupby('customer_id').agg({'date': lambda x: (now - x.max()).days,
                               'txn_id': lambda x: len(x),
                               'total : lambda x : sum(x)})
rfm = df['date'] = df['date'].astype(int)
rfm.rename(columns={'date': 'recency', 
                     'txn_id': 'frequency', 
                     'total': 'monetary_value'}, inplace=True)

quantiles = rfm.quantile(q=[0.25,0.5,0.75])
quantiles = quantiles.to_dict()

def RScore(x,p,d):
if x <= d[p][0.25]:
    return 1
elif x <= d[p][0.50]:
    return 2
elif x <= d[p][0.75]: 
    return 3
else:
    return 4

def FMScore(x,p,d):
    if x <= d[p][0.25]:
        return 4
    elif x <= d[p][0.50]:
        return 3
    elif x <= d[p][0.75]: 
        return 2
    else:
        return 1



rfm['R_Quartile'] = rfm['recency'].apply(RClass, args=('recency',quantiles,))
rfm['F_Quartile'] = rfm['frequency'].apply(FMClass, args=('frequency',quantiles,))
rfm['M_Quartile'] = rfm['monetary_value'].apply(FMClass, args=('monetary_value',quantiles,))


rfm['RFMClass'] = rfm.R_Quartile.map(str) \
                            + rfm.F_Quartile.map(str) \
                            + rfm.M_Quartile.map(str)
```

and what I have now is a data frame like this:

```
 customer_id | RFM
  2          | 313 
  5          | 131   
  3          | 414
```

I want a breakdown RFM score by month like this:

```
 customer_id | Jan | Feb | ....| Dec 
  2          | 313 | 324 | ....| 121
  5          | 131 | 342 | ....| 212   
  3          | 414 | 113 | ....| 333
```

Now the problem for me is that I don't know how to make all those above calculations to be based on month, I thought about looping through the year for 12 times, but the loop will be too large, is there any efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't taken this all the way through with your example, but I believe this will do the trick.

First, make sure your date is actually in `datetime` format if you haven't already.

```
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'])
```

Then, create a new column which will hold the month.

```
data['month_id'] = data['date'].dt.strftime('%B')
```

Then you can group and unstack to get a matrix with `month_id` along the columns, and `customer_id` on the rows. Here is an example with just one aggregation.

```
data.groupby(['customer_id', 'month_id'])['total'].sum().unstack()
```

Giving:

```
month_id January March
customer_id     
2        39.0    10.0
3        NaN     10.0
5        21.0    NaN
```

From there you should be able to apply your RFM score to each column. Note, you will actually have a multiIndex on your dataframe, as you have multiple aggregations. But the principle is the same.